# Propagating event from MediaPlayer in Javafx

Tags: java, events, javafx, propagation

I created a `mediaObject` class that has a few String instances (author, title, album, count; needed for info about the media) and an instance of `javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer`. mediaObject was created because I need additional information to be attached to each music file I want to play and not all files contain this info in metadata. mediaObject construtor takes a filepath to an mp3 file from which it creates its mediaPlayer instance.

However, now I cannot recognize state of the player from the instance of `mediaObject` in my main class. How can I propagate events from `mediaPlayer` to `mediaObject`.

Just as I could call:

```
MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(myMedia);
myMediaPlayer.setOnReady((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            //Do something....
}});
```

I would like to call for mediaObject in my main class:

```
MediaObject myMediaObject = new MediaObject(filepath);
myMediaObject.setOnReady((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            //Do something....
}});
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: Though, I do not understand your question completely, if you just want to propagate the call to `MediaPlayer`, can't you create a `setOnReady(value)` method inside `MediaObject` which just calls `mediaPlayer.setOnReady(value)` ?

Comment: Hm, wouldn't it much better to only do it with a Media Object inside a CustomMedia Object? Why you want to create so much MediaPlayers? You only need one. And then you don't have problems with Events from MediaPlayer